# What does ! symbol mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I really need to know what does this symbol mean when comes after and symbol... For example look at this code

```
glitter(yes) :-
   agent_location(X, Y),
   gold(X, Y),
   ! .
```

Comment: You should read a prolog tutorial or get a good text book. There's much to be explained there. Prolog does *backtracking* to find solutions. That means it explores as many options as it can based upon your given facts and rules to achieve success. A cut (`!`) tells Prolog not to backtrack at that point.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861932/what-is-the-difference-in-execution-if-the-cut-is-present) for an explanation of the cut operator. When you look for [Prolog questions about cut](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+cut), you will quickly see that it is not easy to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` symbol represents `the cut`. You can read more about `cut` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(logic_programming)).
Also, an example in prolog can be found [here](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44).

Comment: Answers based solely upon links are not considered good form. You should explain the cut and then refer to the links for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

To understand "*the cut*" ( `!` ) you need to understand the backtracking process involved in Prolog evaluation of it's code. As you might know, with this piece of code, Prolog only know that the rule `glitter()` with input `yes` is verified if `agent_location(X, Y)` is itself verified when X and Y also verifies with `gold(X, Y)`. In other word, `agent_location` and `gold` must be verified with the same arguments.

This means that Prolog will try to find specific value for X and Y so that everything can be verified. It will go down an evaluation path (evaluation tree) and try a value for X and see if it is possible to continue the evaluation with that same value for X. If it fails (let's say Prolog tried `X = 0` in `agent_location` but `X = 0` does not verify `gold`) it will *go back* and try with another rule for `agent_location`. That's when "*the cut*" comes is. If something after a `!` fails, Prolog will never go check if it can solve with another rule with everything that is *BEFORE* a cut.

In this example, eventually, if everything fails for that particular `glitter` rule, Prolog will want to try another rule for verification. I suppose your original code had another rule specified for `glitter` and, if I 'm not mistaken, the cut at the end of the rule you show us means that if a rule that follows this one fail, Prolog will not go back and check if it can try new values to solve for `glitter(yes)`.

It is usually used to gain efficiency in evaluation and prevent infinite loop.